# Module disabled in app/etc/modules is still showing in admin in Disable Modules Output

Tags: admin, module, configuration, magento-1

I have changed the `active` parameter from `true` to `false` in a module's app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml file, and flushed the cache. I've also logged out and then in again.

However, the module is still showing under "Disable Modules Output in System / Configuration / Advanced / Advanced. I don't understand why.

I thought changing the file in app/etc/modules would 'hard disable' the module - so why is it still showing in that section of the admin panel?

Even if I rename the file to app/etc/modules/disabled_Namespace_Module.xml, the module is still listed. Where does the Disable Modules Output section get its list from?!

My aim is to **completely** disable this module's functionality, and the listing of it there is making me doubt it is fully disabled.

NB. In all other areas of the site (frontend and backend), the module doesn't appear any more.

Comment: Please check  Cache setting and may be you use any 3rd cache system.

Comment: We did have Mirasvit's Full Page Cache enabled, I have now disabled it, flushed cache and manually deleted everything from the var/cache/ folder. Issue is still there so I don't think it's down to cache. Especially as the module has disappeared from other areas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The config section "disable modules output" shows all modules, that Magento found in `app/etc/modules`, and does not check their `active` state.

It will only disappear if you delete the XML file. But besides this configuration section there is no core functionality that uses disabled modules, so you don't need to worry that it's still active somehow.

#### Why does renaming the file not work?

Because the file name does not matter at all. Magento initially reads all XML files in `app/etc/modules`, combines them, builds a dependency tree and then loads the active modules.

Your disabled module is not loaded (its `config.xml` is not merged into the configuration), but the information from `app/etc/modules/disabled_Namespace_Module.xml` is.

Comment: Thanks. So the module is not "active" or doing anything, it's just recognised because it's named within the XML files of that folder?

Comment: yes, that's it.